# Want to create a transparent color overlay over background image but want everything infront of overlay

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want a background, then a transparent overlay, and then all of my content brought to the very front. So far I have

```
#overlay{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:grey;
    opacity:0.5;
    }
```

And I have a `<div id="overlay">` surrounding everything in my html document. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your background?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, can you clarify and create a live example on http://jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: try this out background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.5); apply this to your div for which you want to have transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use thepios answer but use `:before` to get rid of the unnecessary overlay div:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/094/491/original/polygonal-texture-background-vector.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 50px;
}
.content:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.inner-content {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner-content">Your inner content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I'm a little old school when it comes to stuff like this. Making an overlay div gives some advantages though like support for all browsers and for example easier control of animations etc if you want to use something like that :P

Comment: You can use :before in all browsers IE7+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: Yeah it theoretically is so but http://caniuse.com/#search=before says there is some exceptions. But I personally use :before for other purposes and it of course works just fine, no problem.

Comment: The only exception in IE8 is that you have to use `:` instead of `::`. I would recommend `:before` in all cases because it doesn't use semantically incorrect HTML. If you want to use an animation, then you should use a separate HTML container but then it's semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

This would be an easy way of doing it:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/094/491/original/polygonal-texture-background-vector.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.inner-content {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 50px 0 0 105px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="inner-content">Your inner content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This sample has a lot of unnecessary code just to make the sample look nice but you should get the point.

Comment: Thanks, this works, thanks everyone! much appreciation!